# Question about Lemma 5.2.1 McDuff/Salamon Symplectic Topology

Tags: differential-topology, lie-algebras

I have a question about a formula in the proof of said lemma.

> Suppose we have a weakly Hamiltonian action of a connected Lie group $G$ on a symplectic manifold. Let $g \in G$. Since $G$ is connected, we find a path $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to G$ such that $\gamma(0) = e$ and $\gamma(1) = g$. Define $\eta \colon [0,1] \to \mathfrak{g}$ by $\eta(t) := \dot{\gamma}(t)\gamma(t)^{-1}$ (I suppose one should understand this as $\eta(t) = DR_{\gamma(t)^{-1}}(\dot{\gamma}(t))$ where $R_g \colon G \to G$ denotes multiplication by $g$ on the right). Then we have that $$\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{Ad}_{\gamma(t)^{-1}}(\xi) = \operatorname{Ad}_{\gamma(t)^{-1}}[\xi,\eta(t)], \qquad \forall \xi \in \mathfrak{g}, t \in [0,1],$$ where $$\operatorname{Ad}_{g^{-1}}(\xi) := \frac{d}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t = 0}g^{-1}\exp(-t\xi)g$$ denotes the Adjoint action of $G$ on its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. **Why does the above formula hold?**

My attempt: Since the adjoint action is a Lie algebra homomorphism, the rhs is equal to $$[\operatorname{Ad}_{\gamma(t)^{-1}}(\xi),\operatorname{Ad}_{\gamma(t)^{-1}}(\eta(t))],$$ but honestly I am stucked. Has anyone a hint for me how to show this?

Comment: How is $g(t)$ defined?  I see that $\gamma(1) = g$, but I don't see an explicit definition for the curve $g(t)$.

Comment: @Mnifldz Sorry, there were some typos. Now fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluating the derivative given above, we find:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dt} Ad_{\gamma^{-1}(t)}(\xi) & = & \frac{d}{dt} \left . \frac{d}{ds} \right |_{s=0} \gamma^{-1}(t)\exp(-\xi s) \gamma(t) \\
& = & \left .\frac{d}{ds}\right |_{s=0} \frac{d}{dt} \gamma^{-1}(t)\exp(-\xi s)\gamma(t) \\
& = & \left .\frac{d}{ds}\right |_{s=0} \left [\dot{\gamma}^{-1}(t)\exp(-\xi s) \gamma(t) + \gamma^{-1}(t)\exp(-\xi s) \dot{\gamma}(t)    \right ] \\
& = & \left .\frac{d}{ds}\right |_{s=0} \left [-\gamma^{-1}(t)\dot{\gamma}(t) \gamma^{-1}(t) \exp(-\xi s)\gamma(t) + \gamma^{-1}(t)\exp(-\xi s) \dot{\gamma}(t)    \right ] \\
& = & \left .\frac{d}{ds}\right |_{s=0} \left [-\gamma^{-1}(t)\dot{\gamma}(t) \gamma^{-1}(t) \exp(-\xi s)\gamma(t) + \gamma^{-1}(t)\exp(-\xi s) \dot{\gamma}(t)\gamma^{-1}(t)\gamma(t)    \right ] \\
& = & \left .\frac{d}{ds}\right |_{s=0} \gamma^{-1}(t)\left [\exp(-\xi s) \eta(t) - \eta(t) \exp(-\xi s)   \right ]  \gamma(t) \\ 
& = & \gamma^{-1}(t) \left[ -\xi \eta(t) + \eta(t)\xi   \right ] \gamma(t) \\
& = & \gamma^{-1}(t) (-[\xi, \eta(t)]) \gamma(t) \\
& = & \left . \frac{d}{ds} \right |_{s=0} \gamma^{-1}(t) \exp\left (-[\xi, \eta(t)]s\right ) \gamma(t) \\
& = & Ad_{\gamma^{-1}(t)} [\xi, \eta(t)].
\end{eqnarray*}

Here I used the identity that $\dot{\gamma}^{-1}(t) = -\gamma^{-1}(t)\dot{\gamma}(t)\gamma^{-1}(t)$ in the fourth line.

Comment: Very nice answer! Thank you. I guess my main confusion was/is understanding the definition of $\eta$. Maybe you can clarify this: why exactly is $\dot{\gamma}(t) \gamma(t)^{-1}\in \mathfrak{g} =T_eG$? I mean, how makes the product of a tangent vector $\dot{\gamma} (t) \in T_{\gamma(t)} G$ and a group element sense?

Comment: The way in which this makes sense is to interpret this as $d(R_{\gamma^{-1}(t)})_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t))$, however in the context of matrix Lie groups, then the product literally reduces down to matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks, as I thought. Could you please elaborate a bit more on how you get the identity of $\dot{\gamma}^{-1}(t)$? I mean, we have that $$\frac{d}{dt}\gamma^{-1}(t) = Di_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t))$$ where $i \colon G \to G$ denotes inversion. Moreover, we know that $Di_e \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ is given by $Di_e(\xi) = -\xi$.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Deriving that expression is a cute exercise actually.  Differentiate the identity $\gamma(t)\gamma^{-1}(t)=e$.